Prove the following combinatorics equality
$$\mbox{Prove the equality:}\quad
\binom{n}{k + m + 1} = \sum_{j = k + 1}^{n - m}
\binom{j - 1}{k}\binom{n - j}{m}
$$
for $m + k < n$.
I tried to prove this using combinatorics and doing some algebraic transformations, but nothing was working. I guess I don't know an exact combinatorics property needed for this problem.

What have you tried?

Hint: If $A\subseteq{1,2,3,\dots,n}$ of size $m+k+1,$ let $J(A)$ be the $k+1$st smallest element of $A.$ How many such sets $A$ have $J(A)=j?$

@ThomasAndrews if $j<k+1$ then there are no such sets. If $j \geq k+1$ then there are $\binom{j-1}{k}\binom{n-j}{m}$ such sets, but I still can't complitely see how it will help. I understand that we are adding these numbers it the right hand side. How can we calculate how many such sets have $J(A)=j$ generally for all $j$ between$k+1$ and $n-m$? I can't get why it is $\binom{n}{k+m+1}$

Oh, I got it. For $j<k+1$ there are no such sets and for $j>n-m$ there are also no such sets, so to calculate quantity of sets having $J(A)=j$ for $j$ between $k+1$ and $n-m$ we just need to calculate quantity of sets of size $m+k+1$. Thank you

Does this answer your question? How to prove that $\binom{n}{2k+1}=\sum_{i=k+1}^{n-k}\binom{i-1}{k}\binom{n-i}{k}$? That question corresponds to $k=m$ here, but the combinatorial proofs there work similarly for $k\ne m$.

@peterwhy yes, thank you!

Here we have Chu-Vandermonde's identity
in disguise.

We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{j=k+1}^{n-m}}&\color{blue}{\binom{j-1}{k}\binom{n-j}{m}}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-m-k-1}\binom{j+k}{k}\binom{n-j-k-1}{m}\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-m-k-1}\binom{j+k}{j}\binom{n-j-k-1}{n-j-k-1-m}\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-m-k-1}\binom{-k-1}{j}(-1)^j\binom{-m-1}{n-m-k-1-j}(-1)^{n-m-k-1-j}\tag{3}\\
&=(-1)^{n-m-k-1}\binom{-k-m-2}{n-m-k-1}\tag{4}\\
&=\binom{n}{n-m-k-1}\tag{5}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{n}{m+k+1}}\tag{6}
\end{align*}
and the claim follows.

Comment:

In (1) we shift the index to start with $j=0$.

In (2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$ twice.

In (3) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$ twice.

In (4) we apply the Chu-Vandermonde identity.

In (5) we apply the identity from (3) again.

In (6) we apply the identity from (2) again.


